# Embedding LinkedIn profiles on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api, same-origin-policy

I'm using Adobe Edge Animate to build an application where people click on a button and a LinkedIn profile is shown (embedded) on the page. If you're unfamiliar with Animate, it uses HTML, CSS, javascript and jquery. I have been able to embed pages from sites on my own server, but LinkedIn doesn't work. I understand that it's a "Same Origin" issue, so I'm looking for a work around.
(As I'm primarily a designer I do struggle a bit with coding, although I can get it after a few migraines....) I looked at LinkedIn's APIs and couldn't find anything for embedding the full profile. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using AJAX to fetch the results, check out JSONP which works around the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapiprofile